# Need to run ssh-agent everytime I log in

Tags: bash, ssh

Everytime I login, I need to run these commands to stop being prompted for my password each time.

```
will@dev1:~$
will@dev1:~$ eval $('ssh-agent')
Agent pid 4234
will@dev1:~$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for /home/will/.ssh/id_rsa:
Identity added: /home/will/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/will/.ssh/id_rsa)
will@dev1:~$
```

How can I configure my shell so I do not need to do this?

Thanks

Comment: If you are logging in on a text console, you might try putting the commands at the end of your .profile or .bashrc. If you log in via a graphical console, write the commands to a shell script and let that one start via the "automatically started applications", depending on the gui system. In that case, use a graphical ssh-askpass (e.g. gnome-ssh-askpass)

Answer (score 3):

I do not recommand to auto-fill passphrases ...

But you can add the commands in your .bash_profile to avoid typing them :

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This way, you will just have to type the passphrase when you connect !

Hope it helps !