# How to make linux/ssh-agent remember ssh keys?

Tags: github, ssh, ssh-keys

I follow this guide for adding SSH deploy keys:

[GitHub / Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent (Linux)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent?platform=linux)

But every time I want to use them for a git pull, I need to run below again:

```bash
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

How do I make the server/ssh-agent remember the deploy keys?

Comment: Add those [in the `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532063/6309)

Comment: Worked out nicely, thanks. would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

When you run these commands in a shell session, they only apply to that particular session. Once you close the session, the agent and the added keys will no longer be available.

By putting these commands in your `~/.bashrc` file (as shown in "[Need to run ssh-agent everytime I log in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42532063/6309)"), you ensure that they are run every time you open a new shell session.
This means that the agent and added keys will be available for use throughout your entire session.

Additionally, if you put these commands in a resource file that is sourced by all shell sessions, such as `/etc/profile`, then they will be available to all users on the system.

Therefore, adding the `eval` and `ssh-add` commands to your `~/.bashrc` file ensures that the agent and keys are available for use in all your shell sessions, including those used for Git commands.